# Как определить адрес по широте и долготе?

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в android-e можно определить по широте и долготе адрес?

Например, получил я широту 55, и долготу 50 и хочу по этим данным получить адрес вида:

> Москва, шоссе Энтузиастов, д 33.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Comment: public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
      
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
           Geocoder gc;
         loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            String txt = "Текущее местоположение: " + "\nLatitud = "
                    + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
            tv.setText(txt);
        }

Comment: Почему то ругается на Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());